# Spring Boot: Configuring connection manually

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I'm developing an application in spring boot that needs to connect to two different databases. To do that this I had to manually configure the connections. 
Initially everything seemed to work fine but later I realized I had problems with the transactions.
In fact, although I used the transactional annotation on the methods, I realized that every record i was writing on the DB was immediately committed and that if an exception was thrown the rollback did not happen.
It seems as if the transactions were not active.

This is my actually configuration for the first DB.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
    import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "fooEntityManager",
    basePackages = "xx.yy.zz.repository"
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class FooConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name}")
    private String jndiConnection;

    @Primary
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "") 
    public DataSource ds() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return lookup.getDataSource(jndiConnection);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fooEntityManager(DataSource ds) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
          = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        em.setDataSource(ds());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
           new String[] { "xx.yy.zz.entity" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
          = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
            env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));

        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

       return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager fooTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
          = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
          fooEntityManager(ds()).getObject());
        return transactionManager;a          
    }
}
```

I also tried to use JTA but on the contrary this time the application has never written on the DB.
This is the jta configuration.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "xx.yy.zzzz.repository",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "fooEntityManager"
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class FooConfig {

@Value("${spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name}")
private String jndiConnection;

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Primary
@Bean(destroyMethod = "") 
public DataSource ds() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return lookup.getDataSource(jndiConnection);
}




    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fooEntityManager(DataSource ds) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
          = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        em.setJtaDataSource(ds());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
          new String[] { "xx.yy.zz.entity" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
          = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
          env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));

        properties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform",
          env.getProperty("org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"));

        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager fooTransactionManager() {

         JtaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
          return transactionManager;       
    }
}
```

That's all the connection config.

edit1:
I tried to use this configuration in an application with only one connection to one DB. It seems to work fine.  I wrote a transactional method that insert 10 element in the DB and if i throw an error in this method, nothing is inserted in the DB.

Comment: did you try to see if the transaction works verry well with single database ? with spring boot initial configuration ?

Comment: Make sure that you db engine should be 'InnoDB' because transaction only work in this engine if you are using mysql

Comment: yes, i use InnoDB as engine, maybe i found out the problem and it seems to be related to the relation to the order in which I call transactional methods. When i've time a tried a possible solution.